# nextjs Build failed because of webpack errors on CentOS 7

Tags: npm, webpack, next.js, centos7

I want to deploy a nextjs application on a centos server. But when i try to build using npm run build it gives me the following error

```sh
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
info  - Creating an optimized production build
Failed to compile.

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../context/auth/AuthState' in '/var/www/html/projectname/pages'


> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at build (/var/www/html/projectname/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:918)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client-ubii-app@0.1.0 build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client-ubii-app@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-03-31T21_10_01_066Z-debug.log
```

But when i do the same on my local machine runnig windows 10 it works fine

Comment: How are you building/running the app on the CentOS machine? Do you use Docker?

Answer (score 0):

If you has been change in name of file or folder only case sensitive character, this problem may be happen if your remote branch is not updated. Please, make sure if remote branch has the old name of file or folder. If true, fix it because the CentOs is Linux, so file and folder with same words in lower case is different with upper case.